# R: order a vector of strings with both character and numeric values both alphabetically and numerically

Tags: r, sorting, vector

I have a vector of strings that contain both character and numeric values. For example:

```
a=c("ILLUMINA:420:C2D7UACXX:1:1102:14591:91480","ILLUMINA:420:C2D7UACXX:1:1102:14592:3881","ILLUMINA:420:C2D7UACXX:1:1102:14592:37103","ILLUMINA:420:C2D7UACXX:1:1102:14592:37356")
```

I'd like to order the vector so that the characters are sorted alphabetically and the numbers numerically. The structure of the strings is always of the format:
`"ILLUMINA:420:C2D7UACXX:1:<number>:<number>:<number>"`, so actually the order only applies to the last three colon separated numbers.

I did try `mixedsort {gtools}` but the result was the same as using `sort` and

> sort.int, which is:

```
> mixedsort(a)
[1] "ILLUMINA:420:C2D7UACXX:1:1102:14591:91480" "ILLUMINA:420:C2D7UACXX:1:1102:14592:37103"
[3] "ILLUMINA:420:C2D7UACXX:1:1102:14592:37356" "ILLUMINA:420:C2D7UACXX:1:1102:14592:3881"
```

Clearly the right order should be:

```
[1] "ILLUMINA:420:C2D7UACXX:1:1102:14591:91480" "ILLUMINA:420:C2D7UACXX:1:1102:14592:3881" 
[3] "ILLUMINA:420:C2D7UACXX:1:1102:14592:37103" "ILLUMINA:420:C2D7UACXX:1:1102:14592:37356"
```

Is there any immediate solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT** completely change the solution after OP clarification

You can extract the last 3 elements and order,  and you create a data.frame:

```
dat = read.table(text=sub('.*:1:([0-9]+):([0-9]+):([0-9]+)','\\1|\\2|\\3',a),sep='|')
 dat
    V1    V2    V3
1 1102 14591 91480
2 1102 14592  3881
3 1102 14592 37103
4 1102 14592 37356
```

Then you order using 3 columns:

```
 a[with(dat,order(V1,V2,V3))]
[1] "ILLUMINA:420:C2D7UACXX:1:1102:14591:91480" "ILLUMINA:420:C2D7UACXX:1:1102:14592:3881" 
[3] "ILLUMINA:420:C2D7UACXX:1:1102:14592:37103" "ILLUMINA:420:C2D7UACXX:1:1102:14592:37356"
```

Comment: That's pretty close. 
If I slightly edit your solution to:

    a[order(sub('.*:1:([0-9]+):([0-9]+):([0-9]+)',as.numeric('\\1\\2\\3'),a))]

I do get:

    [1] "ILLUMINA:420:C2D7UACXX:1:1102:14591:91480" "ILLUMINA:420:C2D7UACXX:1:1102:14592:3881" 
    [3] "ILLUMINA:420:C2D7UACXX:1:1102:14592:37103" "ILLUMINA:420:C2D7UACXX:1:1102:14592:37356"

But with this warning:

    Warning message:
    In sub(".*:1:([0-9]+):([0-9]+):([0-9]+)", as.numeric("\\1\\2\\3"),  :
      NAs introduced by coercion

Should I care about this warning?

Comment: Thanks! Do you think this can be done more efficiently, as the length of my string vector is around a million?

Comment: In my case, there was a comma missing before the last ]. Result: `a[with(dat,order(V1,V2,V3)),]`

Answer (score 2):

gtools::mixedsort does work in your case, actually:

```
> a=c("ILLUMINA:420:C2D7UACXX:1:1102:14591:91480",
      "ILLUMINA:420:C2D7UACXX:1:1102:14592:3881",
      "ILLUMINA:420:C2D7UACXX:1:1102:14592:37103",
      "ILLUMINA:420:C2D7UACXX:1:1102:14592:37356")
> 
> mixedsort(a)
[1] "ILLUMINA:420:C2D7UACXX:1:1102:14591:91480"
[2] "ILLUMINA:420:C2D7UACXX:1:1102:14592:3881" 
[3] "ILLUMINA:420:C2D7UACXX:1:1102:14592:37103"
[4] "ILLUMINA:420:C2D7UACXX:1:1102:14592:37356"
```

I am using gtools_3.4.2 and R-3.2.0

Answer (score 0):

Here's a faster solution:

```
fields.list = strsplit(a,split=":")
sort.dt = data.table(t(sapply(fields.list,function(x) as.numeric(c(x[5],x[6],x[7])))))
sorted.a = v[with(sort.dt,order(V1,V2,V3))]
> sorted.a
[1] "ILLUMINA:420:C2D7UACXX:1:1102:14591:91480" "ILLUMINA:420:C2D7UACXX:1:1102:14592:3881"  "ILLUMINA:420:C2D7UACXX:1:1102:14592:37103"
[4] "ILLUMINA:420:C2D7UACXX:1:1102:14592:37356"
```